My Hibernate Application is showing error - The application must supply JDBC connections
I'm trying to create a Hibernate application. But while running the application it is showing me error - The application must supply JDBC connections.
Detailed Error is as following:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=54859:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\adv14\IdeaProjects\ProjectWithMaven\target\classes;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.6.0.Final\hibernate-core-6.6.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\7.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-7.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.2.0\jandex-3.2.0.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.18\byte-buddy-1.14.18.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.0\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.2\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.2\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.0\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.2\txw2-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.13.0\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.33\mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar;C:\Users\adv14\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.21.9\protobuf-java-3.21.9.jar org.example.App
Application started...
Sept 01, 2024 6:49:29 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.6.0.Final
Sept 01, 2024 6:49:29 PM org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
Sept 01, 2024 6:49:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
Sept 01, 2024 6:49:29 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:949)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:999)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:13)

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:949)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:999)
    at org.example.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentWithDefaults(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 12 more

Process finished with exit code 1


I have tested that if JDBC connection is working correctly by writing a jdbc test class but it is showing that the connection is working fine.
Test class is as follows:
package org.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JdbcConnectionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myhiber";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "Mysql@1491714";

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Connection successful!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}


The issue could be in your application.yaml or application.properties file. You could check if all the values there are correct according to your configurations.

Please do mention where you have configured the connection let's say If using spring boot then application.properties and finally snippet of those

There are non anonymized credentials in attached configuration.
